# how to mark new content for users using cookies

Tags: php, http, cookies

I am trying to show [NEW] tag for content that my users have not yet seen.

Sadly most users are guests and I do not wish to write every IP in database and store the last visit time.

So I was thinking I could accomplish this with cookies, here is hat I wrote:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/index.php" || $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/browse.php"){
if (!$CURUSER)
setcookie("lastbrowse", time(), time()+3600*24);
}
```

well I cut out some parts for this example to be easier, but this is the part that does the trick for guests.

Cookie is set fine, I get the timestamp in the cookie.

After I do a check:

```
if (strtotime($row["added"]) > $_COOKIE["lastbrowse"])
$new = " <span style='color:#002F4E;font-weight:bold'>[NEW]</span>";
```

so if news are added after the last visit, user sees [NEW] tag by the title.

The problem is I did not know I can not update cookies each time user refreshes a page, I can only set a new cookie once this is expired.

How could I accomplish the [NEW] tag?

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely true. You can definitely update a cookie before it expires. However, you should update the $_COOKIE array immediately after setcookie().
This way, once the <span> renders, it uses the latest value rather than the one that existed when the script was initiated by the browser

Comment: Funny it was not updating, then I deleted the cookie and no it updates all the time. Must have got locked for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Sleavely mentioned, you CAN update cookies, so my code is working and good for everyone who needs something similar!